# Отличия префиксного декремента для итераторов вектора и массива

Tags: c++, операторы

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector v{1, 2, 3};
    // std::array v{1, 2, 3}; // <--

    return *(--v.end());
}
```

Почему для `std::vector` можно использовать префиксный декремент, а для `std::array` - нельзя?

> error: lvalue required as decrement operand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187786/why-cant-i-decrement-stdarrayend

Comment: Декремент применяется не к вектору, а к его итератору.